# Documentation flaw for doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

While googling for ways to perform a `COUNT()` I came across the doctrine documentation ([section 7.8.2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html)) where it states:

> Additionally, you can just count the result of the provided conditions when you don’t really need the data:
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Check there is no user with nickname
> $availableNickname = 0 === $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->count(['nickname' => 'nonexistent']);
> ```

Does the count method actually exist? If so, how do I use it? Throws a 'BadMethodCall' exception currently.

Specifics: Symfony 3.2.2, Doctrine ORM 2.5.6, PHP 5.6, MySQL

To clarify, I am not looking for ways to do a `COUNT()`, I am asking if there is any merit to this line of the documentation.

Comment: Looks like the doc is a bit out of date.  There is no EntityRepository::count() method.  You should submit a document pull request.

Comment: @Cerad Was there a version previously that included the count method? Just curious

Comment: I would assume so.  Check the github repo.  Or maybe they just left out the findAll call in the docs.